# How to iterate over linked list (c)

Tags: c, pointers

A simple linked list datatype called `node` contains a number and a pointer to the next node

the variable x is used to `scanf` capture values from user input

an array `arr` of to hold pointers to the node created

a pointer to the start node `start_ptr`

the first loop captures user input then appends it to the node and moves to the next node
then the pointer for that node is added to `arr`

the last loop simply loops over the node start with the first node and prints each number captured from the user input

```
typedef struct node 
{
    int n;
    struct node *next ;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    // variable to hold integers 
    int x ; 
    node arr[3];
    node *start_ptr;
    node *p = malloc(sizeof(node));
    // check if memory allocated for node 
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    start_ptr = p;
    for (int i =0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i" , &x);
        p->n = x;
        p->next = realloc(p , sizeof(node));
        arr[i] = *p;
    }
    for (  node *tmp = start_ptr ; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        printf("%i", tmp->n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong

when you run the code it accepts the three numbers from the user then starts printing out the last number until it crashes or you terminate the program

can anyone explain why the second loop is not working properly

Comment: `realloc(p , sizeof(node));` is wrong. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. can you be more clear

Comment: Why do you allocate an array if you want a list?

Comment: @vonbrand i use the arr check the numbers

Comment: The `next` field of the last node is not set to `NULL`.

Comment: Why are you using `realloc`? Can you explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that iterates over the list is correct. The problems are all in the first for loop:

1. The `next` pointer of the last node is not set to NULL.
2. You use `realloc` when you should use `malloc`.
3. You don't set `p` to the next element at the end of the loop.

You want this:

```
  ...
  start_ptr = p;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    scanf("%i", &x);
    p->n = x;

    if (i == 3 - 1)     // set next to NULL for the last element
      p->next = NULL;   
    else
      p->next = malloc(sizeof(node));  // otherwise allocate memory for next element

    p = p->next;        // set p to next element
  }
  ...
```

You don't need the `arr` array. For debugging your code you'd better use your debugger.

Complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int n;
  struct node* next;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
  // variable to hold integers 
  int x;
  node* start_ptr;
  node* p = malloc(sizeof(node));   // check if malloc returns NULL
                                    // not necessary in toy programs
  start_ptr = p;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    scanf("%i", &x);
    p->n = x;

    if (i == 3 - 1)     // set next to NULL for the last element
      p->next = NULL;
    else
      p->next = malloc(sizeof(node));  // otherwise allocate memory for next element

    p = p->next;        // set p to next element
  }

  for (node* tmp = start_ptr; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
  {
    printf("%i", tmp->n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code is far from perfect, it just corrects the bugs in the initial code. There is still room for further improvement.

Comment: I used your snippet and got a seg fault

Comment: The code snippet is correct, you did something wrong.

Comment: i can't understand what i did that makes my code broken

Comment: @katysha without seeing your code noone can tell.

Comment: In theory, you should check the return value from `scanf()` before using the value in `x` — in practice, that's borderline unnecessary when the OP is having basic troubles.  It might be as well to mention it, though (and this comment may be sufficient of a mention that no change is needed in the answer).  Less defensible is not checking the result of `malloc()` in the loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler IMO checking if `malloc` returns `NULL` in toy programs is not necessary, as this will in practice never occur. But of course in real worls programs this must be taken care of.